# What is "initiative count"?

Tags: dnd-5e

On page 96 of the Monster Manual (Young Green Dragon), it's stated that:

> On initiative count 20 (losing initiative ties), the dragon takes a lair action...

Does this mean the 20th round of combat (unlikely, as that would be a much easier way of saying it), does it only happen if the dragon rolls exactly 20, or does it happen every round as initiative passes down through 20?

It seems a crazily powerful thing to happen every round, or am I just being too nervous about killing my Starter Set players?

Comment: All good, happens all the time.